# Unable to retrive the FLA permissions for Standard field "BusinessHoursId" on Case object

Tags: permissions, ant, migration, standard-field

I am trying to retrive the **FLA permissions** for a **Case object** standard field "**BusinessHoursId**" by using below package file content,but the Admin profile which i retrive didn't contain the FLA of "BusinessHoursId".

I have to move the FLA of "BusinessHoursId" field from one sandbox to other, how can i achive this there is any workaround for this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ANT Migration Tool doesn't allow to migrate FLS for standard fields of standard objects.

Metadata API Documentation says [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.204.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_permissionset.htm) and [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.204.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm) that you can retrieve and deploy only Custom field permissions. So it is not possible to migrate Standard Field Permission by ANT Migration Tool since it is using Metadata API which doesn't allow to do that.

Anyway you can use a URL Hack to copy FLS from one sandbox to another

https://test.salesforce.com/_ui/common/config/field/StandardFieldAttributes/e?setupid=CaseFields&id=BusinessHours&setupid=CaseFields&type=Case&save=Save&d00eE0000000z6ChIAI=1&r00eE0000000z6ChIAI=1&_CONFIRMATIONTOKEN=Vmp...o

if you have some active confirmation token you can specify it to perform this operation in one click otherwise you will receive message that "The page you submitted was invalid for your session. Please click Save again to confirm your change." and will have just to click save.

The request url is https://test.salesforce.com/_ui/common/config/field/StandardFieldAttributes/e
and parameters are

setupid = CaseFields  - Setup Id Entity name

id = BusinessHours - standard field name (or custom field id)

type = Case - standard object name (or custom object id)

save = Save - command to perform save even in GET request

d00eE0000000z6ChIAI = 1 - Set "Visible" checkbox for profile with Id 00eE0000000z6ChIAI

r00eE0000000z6ChIAI = 1 - Set "Readonly" checkbox for profile with Id 00eE0000000z6ChIAI

_CONFIRMATIONTOKEN = Vmp...o - Confirmation token of action, used to perform action in one click (read above)

Comment: I am still facing this issue in 2022. Do you happen to know if salesforce provide a work around for this or added capability in metadata api @Patlatus

Comment: I am not aware @AsifK